# Does Stack Overflow collect Brave payments?

Tags: discussion

[Brave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser)) is a browser started by Brendan Eich of JavaScript fame.  You can load your browser with bitcoins, which will be send to the sites you visit.

Last month, I loaded $5 worth of bitcoin into the browser.  Brave said I visited Stack Overflow 15% of the time, so it awarded $0.74 to Stack Overflow.

Will Stack Overflow actually collect that money?

Comment: I'm sure that if and when the email comes, the site owners will decide. https://www.brave.com/publishers.html#claim

Comment: 74 cents isn't much to Stack Overflow, and one shouldn't feel like one has to pay them just because one visits often -- especially you, given how much content you have contributed.  Consider whether that money could make a bigger difference to a lower-profile site.

Comment: It would surely cost StackExchange more to spend the time having the conversation of whether or not to accept the payment than $0.75. If it were worth $100 between the few users who might actually do this, it would still likely not be worth the time spent deciding then accepting and processing the payment.

Comment: Trying to estimate how much of $5 will go to Brendan...

Comment: Should it go to Stack Overflow, or the people that wrote the answers? What about the questions? Without good Qs there would be fewer good answers.

Comment: @Flexo I assume the askers and answerers will be allocated the same proportion as they are of the ad revenue.

Comment: You're putting the cart before the horse. Stack Overflow lives on content made by experts sharing their expertise on the site for free (!). It's as if you were trying to pay a scientific journal so that you could referee for them. I'm fine with the business model of SO (well, except that everybody acts as if it wasn't a business venture but rather a hippie colony, which we always see and know it is not), but let's be clear that quality answerers are (among other things) what keep the site going and they all do it for free.

Comment: If you visit the site 15% of your time, you should have loaded it with 13.3 cents and it would have been welcomed on SO meta.

Comment: @Lundin it took way too long for that *penny* to drop

Comment: @AndrasDeak My jokes are far-fetched to the point where I'm happy if I understand them myself. Perhaps if I also post the source code... `printf("Just giving my %1.f cents to SO meta", round(0.15*13.3));`.

Comment: According to the Brave [FAQs](https://www.brave.com/Payments_FAQ.html), an email will be sent to the registered domain owner of the site once the contributions are equal to about $100.00 USD.

Comment: Sketchity sketch...

Comment: Didn't microtransactions die in the 90s for a good reason?  Nobody actually wants to do this.  And why would I pay some 3rd party (Brave) to do it for me and lose 10-30% in the process?

Answer (score 43):

I am an engineer at Brave.

I am also a Brave Wallet user; while [Andomar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346370/54680) represents only $0.75 cents, I represent my own contribution. If users *en masse* are funding Brave Wallets, that regular monthly contribution is nothing to scoff at  That being said, as [@MartijnPieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346370/does-stack-overflow-collect-brave-payments#comment461650_346370) suggested, we will reach out to the staff here eventually, if they haven't registered before then.

Registering to collect is quick and easy: https://publishers.brave.com.

Comment: "I am also a Brave Wallet user" Hey, wait a minute... "we (I am an engineer at Brave)" Oh, good. Had me for a second there.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, Brave will award money to a site on behalf of the Brave wallet user. Brave then subsequently holds this money until the said site registers as a publisher and collects? *Edit*: According to the [FAQs](https://www.brave.com/Payments_FAQ.html), an email will be sent to the registered domain owner of the site once the contributions are equal to about $100.00 USD.

Comment: @JoshCrozier "Hi abuse@example.org, our records show your domain could be worth at least $100. Please click here and enter your bank details to claim the money" - can't see any problems there at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139972/discussion-on-answer-by-sampson-does-stack-overflow-collect-brave-payments). If you want to discuss the merits of the Brave payment model, please take it there.

Comment: @Flexo We don't ask for any banking details; just your bitcoin address. Funds are then sent to you, without ever requesting control over your financial assets.

Answer (score -9):

I've been using the Beta version of Brave for almost two weeks now, having switched from the "Stable Release" almost immediately after installing it. It's an excellent browser - almost identical to Chrome / Chromium, but with several troublesome niggles fixed.

I haven't put any of my own money in, but because I allow the browser to post a couple of ads an hour using the Windows "System Notification" mechanism, I've apparently accumulated 5.5 BAT - that's equivalent to $1.68 in "revenue earned from ads".

The Brave browser tells me I spend over 80% of my time on Stack Exchange sites (it's accrued on an anonymous "per machine" basis, and this just happens to be a PC I use mostly to access SE sites), so in principle Stack Exchange is line for upwards of $50 a year just on *my* account (at no cost to me! :)

There must be thousands, if not *tens* of thousands of relatively committed (high-rep?) users across the SE network. If a sizable proportion of us adopted the Brave approach, that would surely be a useful additional revenue stream for those long-suffering guys who've nobly bankrolled the site for so many years.

I despise adverts with a vengeance, but from what I can make out, Brave represents a credible alternative way of funding "useful, highly-valued" contributors to worthwhile Internet content.

---

In short, I'd like to hope that Brave will continue to gain traction, and that sites like SE will endorse it both as a worthwhile revenue stream (for themselves), ***and*** as a credible alternative (for their user base) to the way corporate advertising budgets currently control much of the Internet's funding of content.

Comment: Users are looking to see less ads not more.  Hence the reason Firefox will provide a VPN service to prevent ads in the near future

Comment: Wow! ***Six*** downvotes, and not a single indication of agreement here! @SecurityHound - since you're the only identifiable individual I can ask, could you explain *why* everyone here seems to think the Brave approach is somehow "undesirable"? I suppose it's possible I've missed something, but to me it looks like a no-brainer that if you don't want ads (and more specifically, you want your browser to drastically restrict "unauthorised personal data mining"), you need something like Brave (as well as a VPN - which I use anyway, but it's not exactly a complete "install and forget" solution).

Comment: ...also, if the issues raised here are too complex to address in comment, can you tell me whether it would be reasonable to ask a separate *Question* here (or on some other more suitable SE sub-site) to find out what's going on here? I really am baffled.

Comment: Like Security Hound said, users are looking to see *less* ads.  Allowing your browser to post ads through Windows sounds worse than ads actually in your browser.  You're better off just getting an ad-blocker to prevent their invasiveness entirely.

Comment: @fbueckert: Like ***I*** said, "I despise adverts with a vengeance" (I allow almost no ads whatsoever *within* my browser). But it's not just pop-up ads on websites that bother me. I don't like the fact that Google clearly "massages" my search results taking account of *their* revenue streams (basically, *advertisers*) as well as their socio-political agenda. I may or may not decide to make a *personal* donation to some content-providing website, but I certainly like the idea of revenue (my own money, or someone else's) going to *only those sites I actually use and endorse*, which Brave does.

Comment: If, and only if, companies opt in to Brave's payment process.  In the event they don't...it just sits there, accumulating interest for Brave.  And in the process, you still have to get ads, only now instead of through your browser, through your OS.  Color me cynical, but I'd find ads through your system notification much more prone to hijacking than within a browser.

Comment: @fbueckert: Perhaps I should "colour you cynical". Brave is open-source, and personally I'd be inclined to trust their security at least as much as that of Microsoft itself when it comes to safe use of "system notification" facilities. And in this context, I'm not really worried about actual *malware* gaining access to my bank details, installing a background bitcoin mining process, or whatever. Mostly I'm just looking for a credible way to finance the Internet without it being so heavily controlled by corporate ad budgets. And Brave seems like a good approach, imho.

Comment: I, too, would like a major change in how ads are currently served; what we have now is a neverending cat and mouse game between browser security features and ad creators finding new exploits.  What I think will happen if Brave gets more traction is that those ad creators start focusing on exploiting vulnerabilities in Windows, instead of trying to change their business model.  The attitude in deliberately exploiting human psychology and browsers doesn't lend itself to trusting them from another angle.

Comment: @fbueckert: I'm getting the impression you haven't really looked into the Brave model. FYI, re ["unclaimed funds"](https://brave.com/faq/#unclaimed-funds), *If a publisher has not verified ownership, then a user’s contributions will be held in reserve inside the browser for 90 days* (after which they're returned to the user's  "wallet" and ***re-allocated*** according to his ongoing browsing habits & preferences). And I don't care if success for Brave means more hackers focus on attacking Windows itself - it works just fine on Linux systems too, so I'm sure that's where I'll go eventually.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn’t downvote your answer.  Just because software is open source does not mean it’s secure software.  Look at the dozens of huge vulnerabilities within OpenSSL in just the last 3 years.

Comment: @SecurityHound, ***Nine*** downvotes now, and I still don't understand why what I've posted here should be so summarily dismissed! All I see in these comments is a preoccupation with *security* issues - specifically with the implication that I'm being downvoted for using Brave rather than Firefox, which makes no real sense to me. Perhaps you could at least address the question I raised in my second comment - *on which (if any) SE subsite can I reasonably raise a separate Question asking why my position here is so reviled? This "silence" is truly baffling to me.